# Files in Swift Package out of scope

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager, swiftpm

I created a basic project with a swift package(let's call it "Foo") related to this project.

I tried printing "hello world" from `Foo().text` from `AppDelegate`
and I get an error:

```
"Cannot call value of non-function type 'module<Foo>' "
```

I then tried to add a new struct or class to this package and I get an error: `"Cannot find {ObjectName} in scope"`
Tests inside Foo all passed.
It looks like I missing some step(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't confuse a module with a public class (or struct). That's what it sounds like you are doing here:

> I create a basic project with a swift package (let's call it "Foo") related to this project and try print "hello world" from `Foo().text`

Saying `Foo()` implies there is a public class/struct called Foo. Is there? I don't think so. You might have a *package* called Foo, which you `import`. But that does not mean that the Foo package has a *public class (or struct)* called Foo.

For example you might see this in your package:

```
struct Foo {
    var text = "Hello, World!"
}
```

But that does not mean you can simply `import Foo` and then talk about `Foo().text`, because this Foo is not public.

Comment: When you created the SwiftPM package inside already exist 1 struct with the same name and attribute var text: "Hello, World!"

Comment: Yes, but it wasn't `public`. Read my words carefully please....

Answer (score 3):

You might of forgotten to import your Swift Package into `AppDelegate`.
Try putting the equivalent for your package in the top of `AppDelegate`.

```
import Foo
```

According to this [Github Issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5099), (if you're using CocoaPods, which you haven't stated in your question.)
**You will have to make the class/struct in your package public.**

You might also have to try like this:

```
Foo.bar()
```

`Foo` being your package name, and `bar` being the class or struct inside it.

Comment: Foo package was imported

I repeated everything from https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/410/
twice

Comment: @YuriyTroyan What happens if you try a Package that wasn't made by you? (Also, are you using Swift Package Manager or CocoaPods?)

Comment: SwiftPM. All external packages work correctly. The problem is with my own packages only.

Comment: @YuriyTroyan Did you try all the things I said in my answer?

Comment: yes. I got a new error: Module Foo has no member named Foo